# How to count total number of visitors to the particular item of the list in blog site

Tags: sharepoint-enterprise, sharepoint-designer, sharepoint-online, sharepoint-foundation, web-part

I have list named : "Posts" in Sharepoint 2010 - Blog site, I need to calculate total number of visitors to an indivadual post or item, Using Hit counter webpart  I have tried but it shows total number of visitors on the page not to an particular post.

Can anyone share the idea of how to achieve this.

Comment: Do you want that number as a report available for admin only, or as an additional field displayed on the post itself (for all visitors to see it)?

Comment: Additional field to be displayed on the post itself for all visitors to see how may page hit does the item got.

Answer (score 2):

Web Analytics will give you numbers very easily.

http://blogs.msdn.com/b/ecm/archive/2010/03/21/introducing-web-analytics-in-sharepoint-2010.aspx

For the identity of users you could try using auditing, that will let you see who's accessing the site. Other than auditing you'd need to look at custom code of some sort that runs when a web-part is rendered.

http://office.microsoft.com/en-gb/sharepoint-server-help/view-audit-log-reports-HA102039795.aspx

Comment: Bagavathi stated in the comments he wanted to display the hit counter on the post page, not only get the count as a report info for admin only...

Comment: Yes Evariste, you are correct.

Answer (score 0):

That one looks to fit your exact requirements: http://spjsblog.com/2010/02/18/hit-counter-for-sharepoint/. It looks from the description you can differenciate pages by the ID of the "post" item (second parameter of `hitCounter`: `isDispForm`).
It's based on JavaScript files to store in a doc lib of your blog site, and a list to create in the blog site as well. The list has to allow read/write access to all users, that's one downside I can see with this solution, but at least you can hide the list; should not be a big deal if this is an Intranet site.
Maybe you'll only have to remove the "Like" part.